# Need help interpreting Displacement time graphs

Tags: kinematics, displacement

In this image is a displacement-time graph of the movement of an iguana. Within the video (Khan academy), the explanation is that between 0 and 5 seconds, the displacement of the iguana is Xfinal-XInitial= 6-(-2)= +8 meters. However, I'm confused in that, isn't displacement relative to the origin or starting point? What is the reason for having graphs start at a number other than 0. Take for example the graph below, I interpret it as the iguana is 2 meters in the negative direction of it's starting position. Thus wouldn't its displacement be 6 meters at 5 seconds? Really hope somebody can help me clarify this point. Thanks for your time everyone.

[image]

Comment: To get the displacement you need to have two time coordinates, it doesn't make any sense to say the displacement at time t=5, you would say the displacement between time t=0 and t=5.

Answer (score 0):

Displacement is relative to the starting point and the starting point does not have to be at $0$; here the starting point is at $-2$ at time $0$.  At time $5$ the iguana is at $6$; relative to the starting point the displacement is $6 - (-2) = 8$.  The displacement is $8$ m in the first $5$ sec.

Here is a real world example of a negative starting point.  A person stands erect in a hole dug out to $1$ m below the surface, and the top of the head of the person extends to $1$ m above the surface.  The height of the person is $1 - (-1) = 2$ m.